# Trabalhar com interrupções em C compilando para pc

Tags: c

Ao tentar responder a uma pergunta do site comecei uma pesquisa densa de como trabalhar com interrupções em C.

**Interrupções** para quem não entendeu funciona da seguinte forma:

Tstou executando meu programa normalmente, assim que determinada coisa acontece, independente do ponto onde estou no meu programa, executo uma função X.

Em programação de processadores, utilizada a linguagem C também, funciona assim:

```
    int duty;//duty 0-100

#int_TIMER0
void  TIMER0_isr(void) 
{

   int led;
   set_timer0(128);
   if(led==0/*&&duty<contador*/)
   {
      led=1;
   }
   else {led=0;}
   output_bit (PIN_B5,led);

}


void main()
{

   setup_timer_0(RTCC_INTERNAL|RTCC_DIV_1);
   setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);
   setup_timer_2(T2_DISABLED,0,1);
   setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC);
   setup_vref(FALSE);
   enable_interrupts(INT_TIMER0);
   enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);

   // TODO: USER CODE!!


   while(true)
   {
      //aqui meu programa principal

   }
}
```

Como isso funciona:

Estou correndo meu programa principal e assim que o contador contar *128ms* ele executa a função `TIMER0_isr();` ou seja, isso é uma interrupção de tempo, a cada *128ms* executo a função x.

Existe também outros tipo de interrupção para processadores, como a de teclado, você pode setar uma função X para ser executada sempre que alguém pressione uma tecla.

O que eu pesquisei tanto e não achei, como fazer isso compilando para um PC.
ou seja, quero fazer que meu programa rode perfeitamente e sempre que alguém aperte uma tecla no teclado executo uma função y. Ou quando estoura um certo tempo executo uma função z.

Como faço isso?

(algo como o método onclicklistner do java também daria certo)

Comment: Seria em Windows, ou DOS?

Comment: Sumariamente, o `onclicklistener` do Java provavelmente gera um evento a ser processado na thread com o looping de eventos, sendo o evento processado assim que a thread se torne idle. Uma interrupção é muito mais baixo nível que isto, e se comporta completamente diferente, além de ser implementada a nível de driver. Seja mais específico quanto o quer, e inclusive sobre o sistema operacional.

Comment: na verdade, não estou criando uma aplicação, é mais curiosidade, por isso não coloquei o S.O.
quanto a isso de ser alto nível e comportamento diferente eu também sei, mas o resultado final é o mesmo e é isso que importa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quando você escreve PC significa Windows, seus problemas apenas iniciaram. Brincadeira, na verdade ficarão mais complexos, pois o sistema operacional Windows abstrai o hardware das aplicações. É isto que torna o sistema e suas aplicações mais confiáveis. Caso contrário, qualquer aplicação, sem o mínimo de segurança e boas práticas, poderia corromper o sistema como um todo.
Resumindo, para as versões mais atuais do sistema operacional, você deve utilizar drivers desenvolvidos em [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx) para poder ter acesso a interrupções e assim poder criar eventos que possam ser disparados para aplicações em modo usuário, pois drivers rodam em modo privilegiado.